# WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0 - Failed to initialize ESB due to a fatal error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm installing WSO2 MI 4.2.0 on a Debian 11 distrubution.
Server is fresh and I've have just downloaded JDK:

```
openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.20+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.20+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Starting the micro integrator returns this FATAL:

```
[2023-08-18 10:35:20,063]  INFO {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 9.67 seconds
[2023-08-18 10:35:20,072] FATAL {org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} - Failed to initialize ESB due to a fatal error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/inbound/endpoint/EndpointListenerLoader
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:220)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.EndpointListenerLoader cannot be found by org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer_4.2.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        ... 38 more

[2023-08-18 10:35:20,113] ERROR {Events.Framework} - FrameworkEvent ERROR org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.wso2.micro.integrator.observability [221]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.internal.http.api; version="4.2.0"

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

I've tried using MI 4.1.0 and it starts fine. Also, using openjdk 11.0.18 with MI 4.2.0 seems to work.

Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to the [bug fix](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8251329) that was [done](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-20-relnotes.html) in JDK 11.0.20. Try adding following two properties to the `micro-integrator.sh` at the bottom of the file where the Java executable is started. Or just stick to JDK 11.0.18.

```
-Djdk.util.zip.disableZip64ExtraFieldValidation=true \
-Djdk.nio.zipfs.allowDotZipEntry=true \
```

Comment: Thanks, adding those I don't get the FATAL anymore.